# Selenium script in the cloud

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to run a python function using selenium on a cloud service without hosting a server? Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: problem: I need to run selenium serverless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few weeks of looking at different options, using node.js and running selenium and headless Chrome on AWS Lambda seemed to be the most appropriate and affordable solution:
credit to @claysmith for the article.

Running Selenium and Headless Chrome on AWS Lambda
https://medium.com/clog/running-selenium-and-headless-chrome-on-aws-lambda-fb350458e4df

@jeffc  comments about books, tools, software libraries, and tutorials are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated comments and spam.

Comment: What about testing your app on Firefox or other browsers? Do they have a headless option?